# Regex for EC2 instance ID

Tags: python-3.x, regex, amazon-ec2

I need a regex that will be able to match AWS EC2 instance IDs. Instance IDs have the following criteria:

- Can be either 8 or 17 characters
- Should start with i-
- Followed by either a-f or 0-9

Valid instance IDs are: `i-ed3a2f7a` or `i-096e0bec99b504f82` or `i-0cad9e810fbd12f4f`

Invalid instance IDs are `e123g12` or `i-1fz5645m`

I was able to create the following regex `i-[a-f0-9](?:.{7}|.{16})$` but it is also accepting `i-abcdeffh`. `h` is not between `a-f`

Grateful if someone could help me out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a regex to match the 8-character ID value and add an optional 9 characters after it:

```
^i-[a-f0-9]{8}(?:[a-f0-9]{9})?$
```

This will match:

- `^` : beginning of line
- `i-` : the characters `i-`
- `[a-f0-9]{8}` : 8 hex digits
- `(?:[a-f0-9]{9})?` : an optional additional 9 hex digits
- `$` : end of line

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rTufUm/2)

Note we use start and end of line anchors to prevent matching additional characters before or after the ID value. This regex will match *only* 8 or 17 character ID values, not 12 or 11 or 5 etc.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the pattern and this is most likely correct. +

Comment: @JvdV yes, I believe that 8 and 17 are the only valid lengths.

Comment: Nice one! I guess i will never fully understand how regex works :) Thank you @Nick

Comment: @MervinHemaraju if you take a look at the regex demo there is a good explanation on that page of what the regex is doing.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be able to just use:

```
^i-(?:[a-f\d]{8}|[a-f\d]{17})$
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/SbmS2r/1)

---

- `^i-` - Start-line anchor followed by literally 'i-';
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group for alternation;

  - `[a-f\d]{8}` - Match 8 times any character from given character class;
  - `|` - Or;
  - `[a-f\d]{17}` - Match 17 times any character from given character class;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

---